# How do I use Artifacts in combat in Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I can't find anything online that answers it. You can equip several artifacts on your character sheet. They talk about doing damage to your enemies. How do you USE them, as in, assign them to a button in your HUD? What if you have more than one artifact? Do they each get a button?

Everything else, like in the Powers screen, clearly says, "Click here to equip to your HUD", but there is nothing about artifacts that I can find in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artifacts are equipped in the Character Equipment screen (for primary) and Enchantment screen (for other artifacts).

All artifacts have passive powers and on-use powers. Passive powers (usually stats like Power, Crit Stike etc) are all active from all 4 artifacts. The on-use power however, can only be used from your primary artifact when activated (by pressing '3' if you're on PC for example).

You can't use the 'On-Use- powers from other, non-primary artifacts.